# How to consider leap year when checking for date difference in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff

I have a situation, I save date in my database by splitting it into month,day,year while my base date is 2010-01-01.

For example,

Say my date is 2017-09-22 so this date will be saved in my database as below

```
basedate = 2010-01-01
comparedate = 2017-09-22
month = 92 //this is the number of month between the basedate and comparedate
day = 2821//this is the number of days between my basedate and comparedate
year = 7//this is the number of years between my basedate and comparedate
```

So say suppose I have to get those records which are from February irrespective of any year I am doing the below query which is working for me.

```
select * from XYZ where month - (year*12) = 1//1 for February.
```

When I am trying to get any records which is having date 12 irrespective of any month or year I am doing the below query.

```
select * from XYZ where day - (year*365) = 12//12 is my date.
```

Here I am facing the problem of leap year. My calculation goes wrong when the leap year is there in the records.

Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: You can store the date as DATE type as well and use sql-server date arithmetic.

Comment: You are simply attempting to re-invent the wheel by not using the `date` type. And the new wheel has issues, as you have already found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE DATEPART(DAY, comparedate) = 12
```

?

And also for months:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, comparedate) = 2 --for februayry
```

Accordingly to the coment below, I came up with another solution:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, basedate, days)) = 12
```

Since `basedate` is base, so it should be common and can be hard-coded here. Here you simply re-determine the date it was and let SQL take care of all leap years :) Then just determine if it was 12th.

Comment: actully the thing is for performance and tracking things we have divided the columns in a different table which does not have comparedate column....

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
playerno, NAME, YEAR_OF_BIRTH
from
tt_players
where
YEAR_OF_BIRTH % 4 = 0 and YEAR_OF_BIRTH % 100 != 0 or YEAR_OF_BIRTH % 400 = 0;
```

Comment: Nice Post! Thank you for this Information!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.